# Default value on a Select2 with an ng-repeat with data coming from an API call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-select2, angularjs-ng-init

I have an angular select2 as follows:

```
<select ui-select2 id="clientID" name="clientID" ng-model="newTicket.clientstate" ng-required="true">
    <option ng-repeat="item in clients track by item.id" value="{{item.clientID}}|{{item.stateID}}" >{{item.displayName}}</option> 
</select>
```

in my controller, clients is set like this (calling a service that returns a $promise from a $resource):

```
TicketService.getClients().then(
    function(clients) {
        $scope.clients = clients;
    }
);
```

I also set the initial value of $scope.newTicket.clientstate in the controller.  Because the call to the $resource is asynchronous, the setting of the initial value happens before the query resolves.

I'm trying to get the dropdown to populate an initial value ("DEMO|DEMO") after the API call completes.  I think that the solution is one of 3 things: setting ng-init on the select, setting ng-selected on the ng-repeat, or doing something in the .then() that happens after the API returns the query.  I can't seem to get the right syntax to work however, and I was hoping to get some advice on how to proceed.

My first effort to solve things (you can see that in the comments below) was to convert everything to an ng-options, but the ui-select2 library is incompatable with ng-op[tions, so I'm looking for another possibility.

Comment: did you try using ng-option on the select element rather than using ng-repeat on the option element?

Comment: You need a way to flag one of the item(s) as "selected" and then use ngSelected on the option, for example, ng-selected="!$index".

Comment: @MikeOhlsen how do I set the value/text using ng-option?  I can only find examples that have very simple data structures, and I'm a little confused as to how to expand that functionality.

Comment: bah, my syntax on ng-option wrong, thanks for the point in that direction.  Answer below

Comment: new wrinkle: ui-select2 is incompatable with ng-option.  Updating my question to reflect that.

Comment: @DrewMcGhie Hm, if I understood correctly, you are loading `clients` only once, no search, no paging intended. If so, why wont you put it on `resolve` of your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this same thing and a guy at work pointed me in the right direction.

It turns out you and I were both trying to over-complicate the solution. All you have to do is:

```
TicketService.getClients().then(
    function(clients) {
        $scope.clients = clients;
        // set the default value after the list comes back
        $scope.newTicket.clientstate = 'yourDefaultValue';  
    }
);
```

Then you should be good to go!

Just make sure that you have initialized `$scope.newTicket` before this, or you will get an error saying you can't access properties of an undefined object.

And I'm assuming that `getClients()` returns a `$promise` object?
Otherwise you will need to do either:

```
TicketService.getClients(function(clients){...}))
```

or:

```
TicketService.getClients().$promise.then(function(clients){...}))
```